# Why TypedArray access is faster when using 32bit BufferView?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, typed-arrays

A couple of days ago i have been playing with canvas Pixel by Pixel manipulation and i have noticed a slight performance increase when accessing typed arrays from 32bit BufferView.

**Example:**

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F3h5K/2/)

```
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var image_data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.height, canvas.width);
var image_buffer = new ArrayBuffer(image_data.data.length);
var image_buffer8 = new Uint8ClampedArray(image_buffer);
var image_buffer32 = new Uint32Array(image_buffer);
var pixel, color;

console.time("array-index");
for(pixel=0; pixel< image_buffer8.length; pixel += 4) {
    color = Math.random() * 255;
    image_buffer8[pixel]    = color;    // Red
    image_buffer8[pixel +1] = color;    // Green
    image_buffer8[pixel +2] = color;    // Blue
    image_buffer8[pixel +3] = 255;      // Alpha
}
console.timeEnd("array-index");

console.time("array-bitwise");
for(pixel = 0; pixel<image_buffer32.length; pixel++){
    color = Math.random() * 255;
    image_buffer32[pixel] = ( 255 << 24 | color << 16 | color << 8 | color );
}
console.timeEnd("array-bitwise");
```

The output is :

```
array-index: 4.273ms
array-bitwise: 3.743ms
```

**The question is:**

Why accessing the array from a 32bit BufferView is faster even if it has bitwise operators inside , as i see it bitwise arithmetic should also cost a CPU time ?

I am interested in the following aspects :

- From the Hardware/JS point of view , why 32bit assignment is faster ?
- How the number of bitwise operators inside the assignment affects the performance ?
- Can i increase assignment performance even more ? Is it possible to use 64 bit chunks or bigger ?
- Can i convert this code to benefit from [asm.js](http://asmjs.org/) platform to increase performance even more ?

Comment: You realize you're comparing 4 value assignments per pixel in a array, to 1 assignment per pixel, right? I'd guess the speed difference has nothing to do with the type of the array. Also: `0.5ms`! Wow! Manipulate 1000 images and you may be able to see the performance difference! (The difference is pretty insignificant)

Comment: When examining timing, you should probably also include the array+buffer creation time and the time to put the image pixel data back on the canvas.  Ditto what Cerbrus says: accessing 1 big array element is faster than pulling 4 little array elements. Perhaps more important than timing is that accessing 1 big array element containing all the RGBA values might simplify your code.

Comment: By the way, `image_data.data` already is an `Uint8ClampedArray`, so the creation of a new array for `image_buffer8` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 8 bit assignment operations are much more expensive than the bitwise operations - you have to take a look at this kind of things from the way modern CPUs are architected: internally all the pathways are (at least) 32bit wide. Moving data from one point to another - in this case a calculated result "costs" the same: if you are moving 8 bit around, it takes as much CPU resources as moving 32 bit around  - so, int he 8 bit case, you are doing the movement 4 times - and even if moving only from the CPU caculating unity to Level 1 cache, it is still 4 times more expensive than a single 32 bit data movement.

When coding in static typed languages with modern compilers, like C, the compiler could, possibly, automatically optimize this kind of code using a "SIMD" (Single Instruction, Multiple Data)  machine instruction to actually pack the four 8 bit assignment as a single 32 bit assignment internally (even if not likely). That is much harder to do with a dynamic language such as javascript, even if it is running in a JITted environment (real time optimization to native code).

Comment: So, like I suggested, the array types aren't the source of the speed difference, the way the variables are assigned is, right?

Comment: +1 Having a single RGBA "frame" can simplify coding which is perhaps more benefit than any timing gain.

Comment: It actually has to do more with the array types: an 8 bit data move "costs" the same as a 32 bit data move. So, unless special care is taken in the other operations, it will always be more efficient to move 32 bit at once.